# Calculate the Number of Users at the Start of the Month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table which looks like this:

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 29/01/2022 |
| 2 | 03/01/2022 |  |
| 3 | 15/01/2022 |  |
| 4 | 01/02/2022 | 01/03/2022 |
| 5 | 01/03/2022 | 01/05/2022 |
| 6 | 01/04/2022 |  |

So, for every row i have the start date of the contract with the user and the end date. If the contract is still present, there will be no end date.

I'm trying to get a table that looks like this:

| Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 |

Which counts the number of active users on the first day of the month.

What is the most efficient way to calculate this?

At the moment the only idea that came to my mind was to use a scaffold table containing the dates i'm intereseted in (the first day of every month) and from that easily create the new table I need.

But my question is, is there a better way to solve this? I would love to find a more efficient way to calculate this since i would need to repeat the exact same calculations for the number of users at the start of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
# initializing dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':['01/01/2022','03/01/2022','15/01/2022','01/02/2022','01/03/2022','01/04/2022'],
                   'end':['29/01/2022','','','01/03/2022','01/05/2022','']})

# cleaning datetime (the empty ones are replaced with the max exit)
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'],format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
df['end'].fillna(df.end.max(), inplace=True)

dt_range = pd.date_range(start=df.start.min(),end=df.end.max(),freq='MS')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['month','number'])

for dat in dt_range:
    row = {'month':dat.strftime('%B - %Y'),'number':len(df[(df.start <= dat)&(df.end >= dat)])}
    df2 = df2.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
             month number
0   January - 2022      1
1  February - 2022      3
2     March - 2022      4
3     April - 2022      4
4       May - 2022      4
```

Or, if you want the format as in your question:

```
df2.T

month   January - 2022  February - 2022  March - 2022  April - 2022  May - 2022
number               1                3             4             4           4
```